# Django Error: Reverse for 'signup' not found. 'signup' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, authentication, django-views, django-templates

When I run the code it gives the message: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'signup' not found. 'signup' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

user/home.html
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0zuB.png)

user/views.py

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWSP5.png)

user/urls.py

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWKBn.png)

main/urls.py

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rbxv.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In 'django.contrib.auth' urls there is no path to `signup` and also `signupView`.
urls:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),

    path('password_change/', views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),
    path('password_change/done/', views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='password_change_done'),

    path('password_reset/', views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/', views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/', views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

you can make your own signup class/function, maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20029776/18129097) or [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62935407/18129097) helps you.